# Defining overshoot and undershoot boundary of entry corridor

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacecraft, reentry, trajectory, entry-descent-landing

I have been reading up on the mathematic of atmospheric entry. I have found different methods to theoretically calculate the corridor width but I don't understand how to define the overshoot and undershoot boundaries. I hope this question will be somewhat coherent, but I'm just very confused.
I understand that the undershoot boundary means the spacecraft experiences too much deceleration and the overshoot boundary means it doesn't decelerate enough, but mathematically I don't know how to calculate this. It seems just a blind collection of data, but it just seems there should be a simpler approach. 
I have found two calculation methods. First a perigee parameter developed by Dean Chapman:
[Link to paper on corridor analysis](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20040030504.pdf)

[image: Chapman's perigee parameter]

And then a planar equation developed from Loh's second order equation.
[Link to book (Chp.8)](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a505342.pdf)

[image: Loh's second order equation solved for undershoot radius]

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for raising my awareness to this. I have added links to the documents I used.

Comment: That's great, thank you!